# How Can I Call Up The Author's Name on a Post

Tags: php, author

For some reason my by author disappeared and I cant turn it back on. I know where I want to put it on single.php at the end of the post, but I can't figure out what code I have to put in for it to display.

Comment: what do you have now that doesn't work?

Comment: If *any* of the answers has been helpful consider accepting one - if you need more information read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 1):

The property on the object for author is post_author. You can access it like this in the loop where $post is your WP_Post object.

```
$author = $post->post_author;
```

If you want to display it:

```
echo $post->post_author;
```

Comment: this will display nothing ;)

Comment: There, smarty pants :P

Comment: :) allow me to be pedantic a little bit longer, what you output is the user ID of the author, which you rarely want to display. probably need to get the user data using the user id and then echo its display_name :)

Comment: You're absolutely right. Derp. ialocin, answer is easier anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Inside [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) you can use the [Template Tag](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags) [`the_author()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author) to display or [`get_the_author()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_the_author) to return the same. For an introduction to outside the loop usage take a look at the Q&A's at the thread [How to get Author ID outside the loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/65548/22534) on here.